# Yet another reference/value type misuse

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, reference

It looks like I didn't manage to understand the concept behind reference and value type lists.

Here, I want to fill up an array of 30000 uint16s, with 125 values at a time.

When finished I want to add it to a list and start to fill up another chunk of 30000 values. However, I only store reference(s) to one array. Here is a test code:

```
UInt16[] ND = new UInt16[30000];
OMD.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) ND[i] = (ushort)i;
OMD.Add(ND);
for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) ND[i] = 13;
OMD.Add(ND);
```

In the second loop the first array member of OMD loses its values and changes to 13.

Comment: List<UInt16[]> OMD = new List<UInt16[]>();

Comment: `List<UInt16[]> OMG = SRSLY?;`

Comment: an array is a reference type - when you change it, everything that points to it will see the updated array. you might want to read a related article - very insightful: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Joanna, thanks for the article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clear the reference and create a new one after each cycle.

```
UInt16[] ND = new UInt16[30000];
OMD.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) ND[i] = (ushort)i;
OMD.Add(ND);

ND = new UInt16[30000];
for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) ND[i] = 13;
OMD.Add(ND);
```